# Android abstract classes bad magic nullpointer

Tags: java, android, polymorphism

I wrote adapter for `RecycledView` which uses 2 types of items. So there are three classes for `ViewHolder`: Base class and 2 it's implementations.

```
public abstract class AbstractCatalogItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public WebImageView icon;
    ...      
    public AbstractCatalogItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

public  class CategoryViewHolder extends AbstractCatalogItemViewHolder {
    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        icon = (WebImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the second icon points on object (`WebImageView`), but first is `null`. How it is possible?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AbstractCatalogItemViewHolder abstractViewHolder,
                             final int position) {

    int type =  getItemViewType(position);

    WebImageView icon = abstractViewHolder.icon;
    WebImageView icon2 =  ((CategoryViewHolder)   abstractViewHolder).icon;
    ...
}
```

[image]

onCreateViewHolder:

```
  @Override
    public AbstractCatalogItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        int type =  getItemViewType(i);

        View v = inflater.inflate(
                type == TYPE_CATEGORY ?
                        R.layout.item_category :
                        R.layout.item_product,
                viewGroup, false);

        return type == TYPE_CATEGORY ? new CategoryViewHolder(v) : new ProductViewHolder(v);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `onCreateViewHolder` method?

Comment: You're calling `getItemViewType(i)` but `i` is actually the result of `getItemViewType(position)` so you don't need to do this. Remove this call and replace `type` with `i`

Comment: As I can't see your `ProductViewHolder` I can't tell if this is also setting `icon`

Comment: @Dreagen ok, thanks, but it's not a ansver of my question)

Comment: If your other `ViewHolder` which you haven't posted isn't setting icon properly maybe it's something to do with that. Hard to tell without seeing it all

Comment: @Dreagen it's simillar to CategoryViewHolder

Comment: In that case I can't see any reason for it not working. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry! There is another icon in ProductHolder. My mistake(

Comment: No worries, glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int passed into `onCreateViewHolder` is already the itemType, remove your call to `getItemViewType` inside of `onCreateViewHolder`.